# Is PXE in a 802.1x network for LTSP possible?

Tags: linux, networking, pxe, ltsp

I have an LTSP server in a network that requires 802.1x authentication. Is it possible to boot the terminals through PXE without disabling the 802.1x authentication? If not, are there alternatives to simply disabling auth for the terminals?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if the PXE boot ROM/image supports 802.1x (e.g. Intel's vPro systems [should support it](http://www.intel.com/technology/itj/2008/v12i4/5-paper/4-embedded-2.htm)).

It seems like gPXE has [some support](http://git.etherboot.org/?p=people/oremanj/gpxe.git;a=commit;h=0d74283bc1d232e93932e18038dc13d94c5b7218) too.

Comment: The gPXE support is very limited, as that commit message says. There's a framework in place to recognize the authentication packets and pass them off to any functions that might be able to handle them -- but there aren't any such functions provided, so the *actual* .1x support is nil.

Comment: It's a commit message from a year ago, but I don't know how it works now.  According to the wiki it supposedly works with [some wireless adapters & WPA-Enterprise](http://www.etherboot.org/wiki/wirelessboot/implementation#encrypted_networks_support).